# android drive api getErrorCode() INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have created one app to read file from GDrive, all work fine in debug mode on Android Studio, but when I'm trying to use the release version I get one INTERNAL_ERROR from (*result.getErrorCode()*).

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            //GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }
```

So I am trying to use the Google Drive API from the [official tutorial](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) for create the same problem.

I have created the key SH1 by the [keytool](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#generate_the_signing_certificate_fingerprint_and_register_your_application)

and created the ID client OAuth 2.0 for the debug key **~/.android/debug.keystore**.
in debug mode the app work fine.
So I have generated a Signed APK by *Android Studio -> Menu -> Build -> Generate signed apk* command with a new key file .jks after that I have created a new SH1 with the new key and after a new ID client OAuth 2.0, but when I upload the release.apk in my Samsung S7 I have the same INTERNAL_ERROR message.
I have changed also the **public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID** in the demo file with my the API client ID.
I have also veryfied the correct key by use this method:

1. open (unzip) your xxxx.APK using unzipper (like 7zip), find CERT.RSA
2. run 'keytool -printcert -file .........\CERT.RSA'

Go back to the console and compare the SHA1's printed with the SH1 in the API Console.

In the Dasboard of Console API I see the request...
I no have idea where is the problem...

**EDIT**
I have created a new account from google.com and with this new account both application works!...WHY? the first account not work? there is some deny flags? where?

Comment: Did you use a sign your app with a [release key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#release-mode)? Debug keys only works for debug mode.

Comment: Yes, I have generated a Signed APK by Android Studio -> Menu -> Build -> Generate signed apk command with a new key file .jks after that I have created a new SH1 with the new key and after a new ID client OAuth 2.0, but when I upload the release.apk in my Samsung S7 I have the same INTERNAL_ERROR message.